# Facebook for iPhone, background wall post

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios4

I am implementing the Facebook iOS SDK into my app... and find no problems with that. BUT, what I can't find to figure out is how to send basic wall post to my facebook app wall.

What I want to do is whenever a user searches for something, the app sends a wall-post with the following text `"@someUser just searched for someSearchQuery"` to my apps wall (not the users wall). 
Offcource this is something I want the user to be able to switch on / off in the settings page, so the user is aware of it.

How can I do this?

Best regards,
Paul Peelen

Comment: I'm trying to do this myself right this moment... if I get anywhere I'll keep you updated!

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question and I think I'm trying to do something more basic than you. If you do find a way to publish stuff without throwing a dialog, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the new Graph API as described here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing

Quoting:
"For example, you can post a new wall post on Arjun's wall by issuing a POST request to https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed"

To use the Graph API from Facebook iOS SDK do something like:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"[your app's id]/feed" andParams:params andMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

where params is a dictionary with following optional keys:
message, picture, link, name, caption, description, source

Comment: i dont know but these part didnt work for me @"[your app's id]/feed" instead i use this @"[profile id or me]/feed"