# Facebook graph Api Problem with number of comments

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello I am using facebook graph api..and trying to display comments of each post..But it is showing only 2 comments per post..some of my post are having more than 2 comments.. I set the limit= 10 in URL

```
url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@access_token=%@&limit=10", url_string, self.accessToken];
```

I have searched but not found why this is happening and also I am getting only my posts which is posted from my iphone app..other friends post on my wall is not visible in my app even my post which I posted on facebook site(not from my app) is also not visible in app..

please Help about this..

Comment: I have edited my answer kindly check if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Facebook for iPhone, background wall post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811845/facebook-for-iphone-background-wall-post)
Check out the above link it will help..

Also make sure you have used read_stream, offline_access, user_profile included in the permission.

Here are the list of permissions you need to use http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/